# Selecting Cases with a Scroll Bar Change on a Chart Series

Tags: excel, vba, charts, case, series

First time posting here. I have a simple line chart which has a series of values from a table. This series can vary depending on the dataset imported into my spreadsheet. I need a dynamic chart plotting a rolling position, which is the data selected within the chart series. I have three Sub's which individually work great, however I want to incorporate them into a scroll bar where I can just click up and down to adjust the range of the chart from the full values, to half the values, to a quarter of the values range.

```
Sub HalfChartDataRange()
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("Stats[RollPos]")
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Rng.Resize(Rng.Rows.Count / 2)

End Sub
Sub QuarterChartDataRange()
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("Stats[RollPos]")
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Rng.Resize(Rng.Rows.Count / 4)
End Sub
Sub FullChartDataRange()
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("Stats[RollPos]")
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Rng.Resize(Rng.Rows.Count / 1)
End Sub
```

Individually those procedures work great, however after creating the scroll bar and assigning the below macro, I just keep hitting errors and I think my syntax is way off. New to VBA and learning slowly, bear with me here ! the below is assigned to the scroll bar, and the scroll bar has its min at 0 and its current at 0 with a max of 2, with 1 increment

```
Sub Scrollbar1_Change()
Select Case ActiveSheet.Scrollbar1.Value
Case "0"
Call QuarterChartDataRange
Case "1"
Call HalfChartDataRange
Case "2"
Call FullChartDataRange
End Select
End Sub
```

The above is on module 4, and the data range procedures/sub's are on the same module.

Getting "object doesn't support this module or method" debug on the select case line

Please help a very stressed and frustrated young analyst ! >:xxx

Comment: Try `Me.Scrollbar1.Value` instead of `ActiveSheet.Scrollbar1.Value`